# eloquent create not inserting everything

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to insert a row in my database using the input from a form.

//PersonController

```
Public function store(){ 
    $input = Input::all();
    if(! $this->person->fill($input)->isValid()){
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->person->messages);
    }
    $this->person->create($input);
}
```

//class Person

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'group_id', 'email', 'phone', 'address', 'isresponsible'];
public $messages;
public function isValid(){
    $validation = Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);
    if ($validation->passes()) return true;
    $this->messages = $validation->messages();
    return false;
}
```

//Form in View

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'PersonController@store')) }}
{{ Form::text('name') }}
{{$errors->first('name', '<span class=error>:message</span>')}}
{{ Form::select('group', $groups, Input::old('id')) }}
{{ Form::email('email') }}
{{ Form::text('phone') }}
{{ Form::text('address') }}
{{ Form::checkbox('isResponsible') }}
{{ Form::submit('Create') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The sql statement generated by

```
$this->person->create($input)
```

is missing the foreign key (group_id) and the boolean value (isresponsible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the **names** in your form don't match the names of the attributes in the database.

```
isResponsible ≠ isresponsible

group ≠ group_id
```

Simply change the names in your form:

```
{{ Form::select('group_id', $groups, Input::old('group_id')) }}
{{-- ... --}}
{{ Form::checkbox('isresponsible') }}
```